# Swift Closures: Cannot convert return expression of type '()' to return type 'LiveSearchResponse?'

Tags: ios, swift, swift4.2

I have two controller.

1. `Maincontroller`
2. `Dropdown`

`Maincontroller`allows users to open dropdown.
`Dropdown` allows users to select a row from the list. selected row value will be passed to `Maincontroller`. In `Dropdown` controller there is searchBar. When user search something, it asks `Maincontroller` to get data for search query. `Maincontroller` will fetch data from Web API and return result to `Dropdown`.

I'm facing the issue when returning data from `Maincontroller` to `Dropdown` using closure.

i'm presenting `Dropdown` modally from `Maincontroller` as below.

```
            let searchVC = LiveSearchDropDown<DropDownTitleTCell>.init(configureCell: { (cell ,object) -> DropDownTitleTCell in

                cell.lblTitle.text = "Dummy"
                return cell


        }, selection: { (selectedObject) in

            print(selectedObject)
            self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        }, search: { (query, spaging) -> LiveSearchResponse? in

            let res  = self.fetchPatients(query: query, forPaging: spaging, response: { (response) in

            })
            return res

        })
        self.present(searchVC, animated: true)
```

Following is the function where i'm fetching search data from Web API in `Maincontroller`. It returns Object of Type `LiveSearchResponse`.

```
    func fetchPatients(query searchText: String, forPaging : Paging, response: @escaping(LiveSearchResponse) -> ()) {

    let params = Prefs.getAPICallParameters()
    var responseData = LiveSearchResponse()

    APIManager.shared.jsonRequest(url: AppConstant.Patient.getPatientList, parameters: params, method: .post, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, onSuccess: { (resposeJSON) in
        if let patientList = resposeJSON["data"].array {


            if patientList.count > 0 {
                var data = [Patient]()

                //success retreived
                for patient in patientList {
                    data.append(Patient(json: patient))
                }

                if patientList.count < 20 {
                    forPaging.shouldLoadMore = false
                } else {
                    forPaging.shouldLoadMore = true
                }
                responseData.data = data
                responseData.error = nil

            } else {
                forPaging.status = .failed
            }
            response(responseData)

        } else {
            forPaging.status = .failed
            self.presentAlertWithTitle(title: "Error", message: "AppConstant.Patient.getPatientList data Key not found", options: "Ok", completion: { (option) in
            })
            response(responseData)
        }
    }) { (error) in
        forPaging.status = .failed
        self.presentAlertWithTitle(title: "Error", message: error.message, options: "Ok", completion: { (option) in
        })
        response(responseData)
    }
}
```

I'm getting compile time error on below block when i'm returning object from closure.

> Cannot convert return expression of type '()' to return type 'LiveSearchResponse?'

```
search: { (query, spaging) -> LiveSearchResponse? in

            let res  = self.fetchPatients(query: query, forPaging: spaging, response: { (response) in

            })
            return res
```

I don't know how to return value to Closures after fetching data from async function.

**EDIT 2**

In `Dropdown` i've declared like

```
public let searchQuery: LiveSearchQuery
typealias LiveSearchQuery = (String, Paging) -> LiveSearchResponse?
```

Initializing

```
required init(configureCell: @escaping CellConfiguration, selection: @escaping Selection, search: @escaping LiveSearchQuery) {
    self.configureCell = configureCell
    self.selection = selection
    self.searchQuery = search
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    self.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
    self.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
    self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 400, height: 400)
}
```

and Calling it like

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    if let query = searchBar.text, !query.isEmpty {
        self.paging.status = .loading
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        let response = searchQuery(query, self.paging)
        if response?.error == nil {
            self.dataModels = response?.data as? [AnyObject]
        } else {
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    } else {

    }
}
```

Can you suggest me the proper way to archive the goal?

Comment: http://www.programmingios.net/returning-a-value-from-asynchronous-code/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're calling an async method then `search` shouldn't return, you should pass a completion block, it will look something like this I think:

```swift
search: {[weak self] (query, spaging, completion) in

    self?.fetchPatients(query: query, forPaging: spaging, response: { (response) in
        completion(response)
    })
```

**Edit 1**

I've got a bit more of an idea with the added info, you should be able to do something like this:

```
public let searchQuery: LiveSearchQuery
typealias LiveSearchQuery = (String, Paging, @escaping (LiveSearchResponse?)->())->()

required init(configureCell: @escaping CellConfiguration, selection: @escaping Selection, search: @escaping LiveSearchQuery) {
    self.configureCell = configureCell
    self.selection = selection
    self.searchQuery = search
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    self.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
    self.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
    self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 400, height: 400)
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    if let query = searchBar.text, !query.isEmpty {
        self.paging.status = .loading
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        searchQuery(query, self.paging) { [weak self] response in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if response?.error == nil {
                    self?.dataModels = response?.data as? [AnyObject]
                } else {
                }
                self?.tableView.reloadData()
                searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
            }
        }
    } else {

    }
}
```

Comment: i have updated my question and posted complete code. Can you revise your answer? what changes i need to do?

Comment: I've added to my answer, it's not fully tested it but it should be near enough right.

Comment: First thing, getting error at `search: @escaping LiveSearchQuery` like @escaping attribute only applies to function types. and  second error at line `searchQuery(query, self.paging)` like `cannot call value of non-function type 'LiveSearchDropDown<T>.LiveSearchQuery' (aka '(String, Paging, (Optional<LiveSearchResponse>) -> ())')`. Please write something what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Hey sorry I got the typealias wrong, it was meant to me `typealias LiveSearchQuery = (String, Paging, (LiveSearchResponse?)->())->()` if it still doesn't work add another reply and I'll have a look at the errors.

Comment: lastly, `Closure use of non-escaping parameter 'completion' may allow it to escape` at line `completion(response)`

Comment: Try this: `typealias LiveSearchQuery = (String, Paging, @escaping (LiveSearchResponse?)->())->()`

Comment: Also in the future you should look into using delegates, all of these completion blocks are quite confusing.

Comment: Thank you Jack. Please Update answer to latest code.

Comment: You're welcome, edited my answer so all should be in line with the comments.